# Count number of files that are not symbolic links in output from "locate"

Tags: symlink, xargs, test, locate

I'm trying to count the number of non-symbolic linked files passed by the locate command. I've tried a number of options and think this is the most promising:

```bash
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | xargs -0 -I{} test -f {} && echo "regular file" | wc -l
```

problem is it doesn't work.

There are 30 files in total, 1 is a symbolic link so `wc -l` should be `29`.

I've tried skipping `xargs` altogether:

```bash
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | test -f && echo "regular file" | wc -l
```

I've tried **not** symbolic link:

```bash
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | test ! -h && echo "regular file" | wc -l
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | test ! -L && echo "regular file" | wc -l
```

What is the most efficient way to pipe `locate` output and count number of regular files vs. symbolic links?

---

### Reply to comments

Some people love `locate` command and some people love `find` command. I hope I'm agnostic but I like to use `locate` when possible. Comments were posted and I'd like to reply to them here in the question:

- `updatedb` takes 30 seconds to run the first time, but only 4 seconds on subsequent times. Having `cron` run it every 5 minutes was a knee-jerk reaction to only once-a-day default. But laptop only runs 10 to 20% CPU usage and there is never any lag.
- After clearing caches `find` takes  1 minute 9 seconds to find a single file.
- After clearing caches `locate` takes 1 second to find the same file.

Here are some benchmarks you can duplicate on your system:

```bash
$ sudo -i
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; exit
logout

$ time locate .hidden.c | wc -l
1

real    0m0.790s
user    0m0.758s
sys     0m0.028s

$ sudo -i
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; exit
logout

$ time find / iname '.hidden.c'  2>/dev/null | wc -l
1888926

real    1m9.044s
user    0m5.158s
sys     0m15.004s

$ sudo -i
# sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches; exit
logout

$ time sudo updatedb

real    0m29.323s
user    0m1.267s
sys     0m4.784s

$ time sudo updatedb

real    0m3.592s
user    0m0.479s
sys     0m1.211s
```

`find` is unquestionably a lot more robust than `locate` but `locate` is many times faster and has an easier to remember syntax.

It's true you have to remember to run `sudo updatedb` or one-time pass the argument `-u` to the `locate` command to update the database to include files created today or exclude files deleted today. But on the other hand with `find` you have to remember to pass the `2>/dev/null` parameter.

I chose to have `cron` run `updatedb` every five minutes because my laptop is under-worked in the first place and I'm lazy in the second place.

Answer (score 2):

This command came close:

```
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | xargs -0 -I{} test -f {} && echo "regular file" | wc -l
```

Problems:

- You're using nul delimited input with xargs, but `locate` isn't providing nul delimited output.
- The `&& echo` is run for the `locate | xargs` pipe as a whole and not for the individual runs of `test`

Try:

```
locate -0r "$PWD.*\.c$" | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'test -f "$1" && echo "regular file"' _  {} | wc -l
```

- enabling nul delimited output for `locate` with `-0`
- combining the `test` and `echo` (this could be improved with a loop over arguments in `sh -c` so that multiple files are processed per invocation of `sh`)

There's still the problem of regex operators appearing in `$PWD`.

Comment: Deja vu @ regex...Why is it "regular expression" seems so irregular to me :( FTR `-`f counts a symbolic link as a regular file so the total is 30. I have to use `! -L` to get 29 for Zanna's answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023244/how-can-i-count-files-with-a-particular-extension-and-the-directories-they-are/1023474?noredirect=1#comment1663184_1023474

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, `-f` counts a symbolic link as a regular file only if the link points to regular file. `-f` tests for _regular_ file after symlink resolution. It would return false for a symlink to non-regular file (device, fifo, directory...).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Sorry I read your comment 13 hours too late. The project scope is to exclude symbolic links even if they do point to a valid `.c` regular file. Test data was provided by the Zanna in the link above.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than parsing the output of `locate` (which is fragile and may miss things that have changed since its database was last updated, or that are not available to *all* users), use `find`.

The following will find all `.c` files in the current directory that are regular files (not symbolic links):

```
find . -type f -name '*.c'
```

Given the directory structure

```
.
|-- file-a.c
|-- file-b.c
|-- file-c.c
|-- file-d.c
|-- link-b.c -> file-b.c
`-- link-d.c -> file-d.c
```

This would return

```
./file-a.c
./file-b.c
./file-c.c
./file-d.c
```

To count them:

```
find . -type f -name '*.c' | wc -l
```

or, if you have filenames with newlines in their names,

```
find .//. -name '*.c' -type f | grep -c //
```

Doing the same for symbolic links would involve changing the `-type f` to `-type l`.

Comment: I have `updatedb` running in `cron` every five minutes. `find` is faster than `locate` on a single directory with a few subdirectories. For many drives and partitions though, `locate` is infinitely faster. I was attempting a `locate` only answer for this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023244/how-can-i-count-files-with-a-particular-extension-and-the-directories-they-are/1023474?noredirect=1#comment1663184_1023474) in **Ask Ubuntu**.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You are aware that updating the `locate` database more or less involves running a `find` across the whole filesystem, and that doing that every five minutes is a bit silly? I forgot to mention that `locate` will also miss files that the `nobody` user can not access (for example in directories that you have protected).

Comment: I appreciate your comment and have read many similar ones in the past. I updated my question with some benchmarks that you and others can repeat on your own systems. I appreciate the value and popularity of the `find` command but the purpose of this investigation was to see how the `locate` command could be used instead of the `find` command like the other answers to the **Ask Ubuntu** question were using. I hope you aren't offended...

Comment: @Kusalananda, that very much depends on the `locate` implementation, several allow users to list their own files. Some may employ tricks to avoid re-scanning the full file system.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
c_regular_files=(
  ${(0)^"$(locate -0 "${${PWD%/}//(#m)[]\\*?]/\\$MATCH}/*.c")"}(N.)
)
echo there are at least $#c_regular_files regular files whose name ends in .c
```

- We need to escape the `[`, `?`, `\` and `*` in `$PWD` for `locate` not to interpret them as wildcard operators (it would be even worse with `-r` for regexps which have more operators including `.`, common in file names)
- `$PWD` == `/` has to be treated specially; with `$PWD` instead of `${PWD%/}`, we would be running `locate -0 "//*.c"` which wouldn't return anything.
- `-0` for files to be NUL-delimited (newline wouldn't work as it's allowed in file paths).
- `.` is for *regular* file. Contrary to `[ -f`, that  excludes symlinks to regular file. If you want every non-symlink `.c` file (allowing any other type of file like directory, fifo, socket...), replace `.` with `^@`.

In any case note that `locate` returns a list based on the last time the `locate` database was updated which may not reflect the current reality.

Comment: Does that also handle a filename with, say `\*` in it? Maybe you could provide the canonical answer to the question that inspired this one: https://askubuntu.com/q/1023244/158442

Comment: @muru, with a PWD='/foo\*bar', that should do a `locate '/foo\\\*bar/*.c'` which works for me with `mlocate` 0.26 and should work  with  any implementation where backslash is used as an escape operator (I expect all would). There could still be potential problems with file names containing sequences of bytes nor forming valid characters or charsets where the encoding of some characters contain the encoding of wildcard characters. Fixing the locale to C (for both locate and zsh) would address those.

Comment: Thank you for this bullet proof answer. As you alluded `[ -f` wasn't working on test data so I had used `[ ! -L` instead. As @muru mentioned this question was to address an answer in sister-site **Ask Ubuntu**: https://askubuntu.com/a/1023474/307523

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in bash. The first line generates error: `bash: set: extendedglob: invalid option name`. The second line `c_regular_files=(${(0)^"$(locate -0 "${${PWD%/}//(#m)[]\\*?]/\\$MATCH}/*.c")"}(N.))` has error: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes. Like I said, it's for zsh. Zsh is a shell with many more features than bash generally a superset of bash but with a few significant differences as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I appreciate that **zsh** is superior to **bash** but for the Q&A few would be receptive to installing zsh. Most Ubuntu users prefer the "canonical way" and use the default programs

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" | parallel 'test -f {} && echo "regular file"' | wc -l
```

As you can see it is extremely close to your initial attempt.

If you have fewer than 100 hits, you can use that GNU Parallel sets $? to the number of failed jobs up to 100 (THIS DOES NOT SCALE):

```
ls  *txt | parallel \! test -f {}
echo $?
```

If you need it even faster:

```
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" |
  perl -ne 'chomp; -l $_ or $s+= -f $_; END{print "$s\n"}'
```

Or the combination:

```
locate -r "$PWD.*\.c$" |
  parallel --block 10k --pipe -q perl -ne 'chomp; -l $_ or $s+= -f $_; END{print "$s\n"}' |
  awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```

Comment: +1 because it is interesting and has promise but I'm afraid it doesn't work. I installed `moreutils`. If I run `locate .bashrc | wc -l` I get `9`. If I run `locate .bashrc | parallel 'test -f {} && echo "regular file"' | wc -l` I get `0` but it should be `9` on my system.

Comment: You need GNU Parallel, not parallel from moreutils (see 2009 of https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html)

Comment: When I tried `parallel` command in **Ubuntu 16.04** (Debian based) it recommended the `moreutils` package. I'll remove it tonight and install the GNU version. The multi-core processing abilities of `parallel` is enticing because some operations like `stat` can be very taxing for many files on a single CPU core.

Comment: I read your link and the history of `parallel`, `moreutils` version of parallel (duplicate), `xargs`, `xxargs`, xxargs+parallel` and `GNU parallel` but what was missing is the download link??? I found this link: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/ though. Is the file `parallel-20120122.tar.bz2` the most recent? Also why not call your program `pxargs` (parallel xargs) to disambiguate from the other `parallel` and stress the drop in replacement for `xargs` angle?

Comment: Latest version is always https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/parallel-latest.tar.bz2 which currently is 20180322. The naming confusion is less and less these days: moreutils' parallel is being split into a separate package in many distributions (e.g. Ubuntu 17.04) and you can then install both moreutils and GNU Parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the proper link. I've downloaded the tape archive file. But got duplicates in my `~/Downloads` directory during extraction due to  previous tars.I think I'll write a bash script to automate `.tar.xxx` installs so `parallel` testing might be pushed back a couple of days.